# having trouble to run my first flutter app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm facing an error when i try to run a flutter project in android studio or in command line with **flutter run**
it gives me this error

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:851)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2055)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

the output of **flutter doctor -v**

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1425], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (5 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.34.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)

## • No issues found!

PS:
and i had another issue a while back so i changed **flutter.gradle** file like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna say exactly how I overcome this issue .some steps might not be necessary but i did all of this :

1. unistall flutter and android studio
2. install the lastest version of both (android studio and flutter )
3. then add

> maven {
>               url 'http://download.flutter.io'
>           }

in your build.gradle file

4. then change compile and target sdk version to 29 (just find them and replace 29 with 28 )
   C:\Users\$USER\AndroidStudioProjects\$projectname\android\app\build.gradle
   like this

   compileSdkVersion 29
   targetSdkVersion 29

this is how it got solved for me . i hope it works for you guys too .

Comment: Telling someone not to use the language or framework they’re asking a question about doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: yeah that s true i found the solution

Comment: Thank you! That’s a much improved answer. Also, I had missed that you were the OP when I left that comment, so mistook your frustration for snark. Regardless, the update is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Gradle files are damaged.

Here's what you need to do:

> open $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/dists and delete gralde-xxx-all . then execute command: flutter run again.

More info [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13645#issuecomment-439251671).

Comment: Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)  i just did what you said and it stuck here

Comment: I had this happen to me before. You either need to clean more stuff in your HDD (this was my case) or you need to fix some network settings. Here are 4 helpful links. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27310
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47392
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238026/flutter-taking-an-unexpectedly-long-time-for-connecting-to-browser

Answer (score 1):

Go into your Project folder and in the

> gradle
> wrapper
> gradle-wrapper

change the number from:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip`